# Change filter predicate order in index page - ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

**Versions:**

- Rails - 3.2.22.2
- ActiveAdmin - 0.6.6
- Ruby - 2.3.8p459

Need help in changing the default filter order for string input type in the index page sidebar filters.

> Default order is Contains, Equals, StartsWith, EndsWith. Need to change this as Equals, Contains, and etcetera

**Extras:**

Way to do the above requirement in rails v5.2.1 is to add below lines at the end of active_admin.rb file

```
ActiveAdmin::Inputs::Filters::StringInput.filters.clear
ActiveAdmin::Inputs::Filters::StringInput.filter(:equals, :starts_with, :ends_with, :contains)
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep digging, I got the answer.

For active-admin v0.6.6, it should be like

```
ActiveAdmin::Inputs::FilterStringInput.filters.clear
ActiveAdmin::Inputs::FilterStringInput.filter(:equals, :starts_with, :ends_with, :contains)
```

**Replacing Filters::StringInput to FilterStringInput** will work